# remove double quotes and leave brackets from dictionary value

Tags: dictionary, data-wrangling

I have a dict as follows:

```
d= {'items': {'Tags': {'contacts': "['first_names', 'names']"}}}
```

I need this to be:

```
d= {'items': {'Tags': {'contacts': ['first_names', 'names']}}}
```

I have tried accessing the value to convert to string and remove the quote but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

d = {"items": {"Tags": {"contacts": "['first_names', 'names']"}}}

d["items"]["Tags"]["contacts"] = literal_eval(d["items"]["Tags"]["contacts"])
print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
{'items': {'Tags': {'contacts': ['first_names', 'names']}}}
```